# How Read .text file line by line and the stored in database in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, vb.net, text-files

I have a module which upload report and then stored in database in sql server. Now I have come up with this code to read .txt file line by line.

```
Protected Sub ibtnTxtUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim jsbldr As New StringBuilder
    Try
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

            Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

            If Extension = ".txt" Then

                Dim Request_Val As String = ""

                Dim sFileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName


                'Read Line by Line

                Using sRead As New StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
                    sFileName = sRead.ReadToEnd
                End Using

                Dim sFileLines() As String = sFileName.Split(vbCrLf)

                'Trim the line
                Dim dt As New DataTable("XmlData")

                dt.Columns.Add("Item", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("Rev", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("Locator", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("UOM", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Double))

                Dim writer As New StringWriter
                Dim sline As String

                Dim i As Integer = 0
                Dim lStart As Boolean = False

                For Each sline In sFileLines

                    If sline.TrimStart.TrimEnd <> "" Then

                        If lStart = True Then

                            If sline.Substring(0, 10).TrimStart.TrimEnd <> "-------" Then

                                Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                                newRow("Item") = sline.Substring(0, 32).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                                newRow("Description") = sline.Substring(33, 53).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                                newRow("Rev") = sline.Substring(86, 3).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                                newRow("Locator") = sline.Substring(89, 26).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                                newRow("UOM") = sline.Substring(115, 3).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                                newRow("Quantity") = sline.Substring(124, 7).TrimStart.TrimEnd

                                dt.Rows.Add(newRow)

                            End If

                        End If

                        If sline.Substring(0, 32).TrimStart.TrimEnd = "Item" Then
                            lStart = True
                        End If

                        If sline.TrimStart.TrimEnd = "" Then
                            lStart = False
                        End If
                    End If


                Next


                'Execute SQL Stored Procedure
                Using cn As New SqlConnection(cls.strConnString)

                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()

                        With cmd

                            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                            .CommandText = "USP_XML_SOH_ACCOUNT_MAINT"
                            .Parameters.Add("@XMLdata", SqlDbType.Xml) : .Parameters("@XMLdata").Value = writer.ToString
                            .Parameters.Add("@USR_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30) : .Parameters("@USR_ID").Value = cls.GetUserName
                            .Parameters.Add("@FILE_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) : .Parameters("@FILE_NAME").Value = sFileName
                            .Parameters.Add("@RET_VAL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
                            .Parameters("@RET_VAL").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

                            .Connection = cn
                            cn.Open()

                            .ExecuteNonQuery()

                            Request_Val = .Parameters("@RET_VAL").Value.ToString

                        End With

                    End Using

                End Using


                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#grid-div').height(250);$.blockUI({message: 'Updating data...',css: {border: 'none',padding: '15px', width: '15%', left: '40%',backgroundColor: '#000','-webkit-border-radius': '10px','-moz-border-radius': '10px',opacity: .5,color: '#fff'}});setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); " & _
               " $('#dialog-message').html('<table style=""border-style:hidden;""><tr><td style=""padding:5px;""> <img src=""images/gridview/check_circle_64x64.png""/></td><td>" & Request_Val.ToString & "</td></tr></table>');" & _
               "$('div#dialog-message').dialog ({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window}).prev ().find ('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); " & _
               "var varCounter = 0; var varName = function(){ if(varCounter < 1){ varCounter++; $('#dialog-message').dialog('open'); } else {clearInterval(varName);}};setInterval(varName, 2000);}); </script>")

            Else

                jsbldr.Append("<script>")
                jsbldr.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
                jsbldr.Append("$('div#dialog-message').dialog ({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window}).prev ().find ('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();")
                jsbldr.Append("$('#dialog-message').html('<table style=""border-style:hidden;""><tr><td style=""padding:5px;""> <img src=""images/gridview/exclamation_circle_64x64.png""/></td><td>Invalid file format, please use .xlsx excel file extention.</td></tr></table>');")
                jsbldr.Append("$('#dialog-message').dialog('open');")
                jsbldr.Append("});")
                jsbldr.Append("</script>")
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Javascript", jsbldr.ToString)

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        jsbldr.Append("<script>")
        jsbldr.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
        jsbldr.Append("$('div#dialog-message').dialog ({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window}).prev ().find ('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();")
        jsbldr.Append("$('#dialog-message').html('<table style=""border-style:hidden;""><tr><td style=""padding:5px;""> <img src=""images/gridview/exclamation_circle_64x64.png""/></td><td>Uploading SOH Account file template encounter error, please check the file.</td></tr></table>');")
        jsbldr.Append("$('#dialog-message').dialog('open');")
        jsbldr.Append("});")
        jsbldr.Append("</script>")
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Javascript", jsbldr.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Here's the actual text file, in every end of the record there is an end symbol, I'm trying to put here but it can't capture.

```
  Item                          Description                                         Rev Locator                   UOM     Quantity
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------   --- ------------------------- --- ------------
  604K23660                      KIT-FDR HCF MSI                                        ANG.2.0.0                 PC          1.00

  604K23670                      KIT FEEDER TM                                          ANG.2.0.0                 PC          3.00

  604K26021                      LEN ASSY                                               ANG.2.0.0                 PC          1.00

  CT200541                       AP/DCC4400/4300/3300/2200 Cartridge Toner              ANG.2.0.0                 Unt         3.00
                             (Magenta)
  CT200542                       AP/DCC4400/4300/3300/2200 Cartridge Toner (Yellow)     ANG.2.0.0                 Unt         6.00

 Subinventory: NEI-OLO    Description: Non-Equipment Inventory of Olongapo

  Item                          Description                                         Rev Locator                   UOM     Quantity
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------   --- ------------------------- --- ------------
  CT350769                       DC-III 3007/2007 Drum Cartridge Standard                                         PC          7.00

  CT350851                       AP/DC-IV C5570/4470/3370/3371/2270 Long Life Drum                                PC          2.00
                             Cartridge (1 piece)
```

I put some condition in my **For Each** for the file. Now the condition read each line where to start reading and where to end and then add each row in my datatable, it loop until **lStart = FALSE** but I have an error on my condition if the record reached the ending symbol **lSTart = False** and then will loop again to find the "Item".

```
For Each sline In sFileLines

                If sline.TrimStart.TrimEnd <> "" Then

                    If lStart = True Then

                        If sline.Substring(0, 10).TrimStart.TrimEnd <> "-------" Then

                            Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                            newRow("Item") = sline.Substring(0, 32).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                            newRow("Description") = sline.Substring(33, 53).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                            newRow("Rev") = sline.Substring(86, 3).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                            newRow("Locator") = sline.Substring(89, 26).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                            newRow("UOM") = sline.Substring(115, 3).TrimStart.TrimEnd
                            newRow("Quantity") = sline.Substring(124, 7).TrimStart.TrimEnd

                            dt.Rows.Add(newRow)

                        End If

                    End If

                    If sline.Substring(0, 32).TrimStart.TrimEnd = "Item" Then
                        lStart = True
                    End If

                    If sline.TrimStart.TrimEnd = "" Then
                        lStart = False
                    End If
```

Here's my condition on the ending symbol, apparently the symbol can't capture here,but on visual studio it can.

```
If sline.TrimStart.TrimEnd = "" Then
                    lStart = False
                End If
```

After reading all the data, I need an XMLData to write this on the database in sql server. So I have a stored procedure for this. It is not working yet because the error on my For Each Condition.

I appreciate the suggestion and help, feel free to right my codes. Thanks

Comment: text files are just like strings of something you would type on your keyboard. you are done as I can see. What is your text file looks like?

Comment: @Chillzy I edited my question, on the lower part I put my text file looks like.

Comment: you have control on how the file is generated? You have to see this file like an excel sheet. imagine the grid in there and find a way to handle your string to fit then into columns

Comment: no i don't have control on it. the report is generated by another person.

Comment: rev locator column is the paper size?

Comment: @Chillzy "REV" column is blank in the report while "Locator" is the organization, sorry for the locator I forgot to put some value.

Comment: does the file contains blank to fill the spaces for the columns or it just you spreading it a little bit but in fact there's only just one space? Can you have a different separator like a tab or coma

Comment: @Chillzy I updated the text file, that's the actual output of the text file.

Comment: Gracias! If you had put this in the first place we would avoided a lot of back and forth. This is what you call fixed size column. on a printer or on a screen depending on the font you are using this will not align properly. In a text file which is just ASCII code characters. In a string variable "I" is the same size as a "M" but clearly on your screen it isn't. split each line into their column's size. use strings.mid()

Comment: @Chillzy Sorry, I'm a bit confuse on how to do it?

Comment: What's the error? what happens when you reach this position in the file? Subinventory: NEI-OLO    Description: Non-Equipment Inventory of Olongapo

Comment: This line will also throw an error "                            (Magenta)"  and also this "Cartridge (1 piece)" since it isn't an empty line and also not an entry line. it's the left over that didn't fit the column. you need to take these in consideration. Also only put what is related to your question. Only put the code that reads your file

Comment: @Chillzy I'm still considering the Description with 2 row, I will add also condition on that.

Comment: @Chillzy this is one of my error, Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <quantity> in Quantity Column.  Expected type is Double.

Comment: lol then convert it! If  Double.TryParse(yourstring,returnvalue)= True Then

Comment: @Chillzy I got it correct now, thanks

Comment: vote up my answer too please!

Comment: @Chillzy my problem is this This line will also throw an error " (Magenta)" and also this "Cartridge (1 piece)" since it isn't an empty line and also not an entry line. it's the left over that didn't fit the column.

Comment: before adding the data to your table, read ahead to see what is the next line. Instead of doing a for each loop do it with a counter for xcount=0 to fileslines.count-1....then you can access your line with an index or add a counter in your loop to keep track of your line count and access one line ahead. this way you can keep your for each and your data to your table after you checked the data ahead.

Comment: @Chillzy can i used an append method here.

Comment: like this  newRow("Description") = newRow("Description") & " " & sline.Substring(33, 53).TrimStart.TrimEnd

Comment: @Chillzy I got an error, Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Comment: You don't give me no code or anything. I do not see your screen. When you get to the last line, remember there's no line after and you cannot read ahead....Also learn about break points

Comment: @Chillzy sorry for that, `If sline.Substring(0, 32).TrimEnd = "" And sline.Substring(33, 53).TrimEnd  <> ""  Then   newRow("Description") = newRow("Description") & " " & sline.Substring(33, 53).TrimStart.TrimEnd`

Comment: update the code in your question to only include the part reading your file. this getting complicated using comments. Which line number does it crash at?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to indicate that the problem has been resolved. Accepting an answer is enough to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked to put them in a list but you could use an array. I don't need to show you how to insert values inside excel as you seem to know already. Skip the 2 first line or insert them as headers inside your excel file. concept is the same.

```
        Dim xstr As String = "007K88431                      GEAR ASSY-20/46                                        ANG.2.0.0                 PC          1.00"
        Dim xline As New List(Of String)
        xline.Add(Strings.Mid(xstr, 1, 30).Trim)
        xline.Add(Strings.Mid(xstr, 31, 56).Trim)
        xline.Add(Strings.Mid(xstr, 87, 26).Trim)
        xline.Add(Strings.Mid(xstr, 113, 4).Trim)
        xline.Add(Strings.Mid(xstr, 117).Trim)
```

Comment: this would be put on the 'Check Template Column'?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, now I have come up with a code for reading each line but I have problem with my condition. I updated my code above so that it will be clear. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score -1):

That seems like a lot of surpfluous code for uploading a file!  To load a Text file or a CSV, which is the same thing, run the following script.

```
BULK INSERT TmpStList FROM 'c:\TxtFile1.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","')
```

Comment: So I just need to change my extension to .txt and then put this code `If Extension = ".txt" Then BULK INSERT TmpStList FROM 'c:\TxtFile1.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","')`